# Create Header for Kendo UI Menu for sub items group

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, menu, header

I'm trying to add a Header to a kendo Menu items group when the item is selected its subitems group should display a header with the parent name. I'm creating the menu thru a datasource dynamically. How can I add a `<div>` or `<h2>` tag to achieve this?

Example:

```
Menu 1 ^
  Item 1   >   Item 1
  Item 2       Sub Item 1
  Item 3       Sub Item 2
               Sub Item 3
```

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you build the menu dynamically you can place disabled menu items to act as the headers and change their style to your liking so they don't look like disabled menu items.

See the snippet for a demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
  
<style>
  .menu-header span {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
  
  .menu-header span {
    color: red !important;
  }
</style>
  
</head>
<body>
  
  
<ul id="menu"></ul>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").kendoMenu({
      dataSource:
      [{
         text: "Menu",
         items: [{
           text: "Sub Item 1"
         }, {
           text: "Sub Item 2",
           items: [{
             text: "Sub Item 2",
             enabled: false,
             cssClass: "menu-header"
           }, {
             text: "Sub-Sub Item 1"
           }, {
             text: "Sub-Sub Item 2"
           }]
         }]
       }]
    })
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```